# how to check if there is a division by zero in c

Tags: c, divide-by-zero

```
#include<stdio.h>
void function(int);

int main()
{
     int x;

     printf("Enter x:");
     scanf("%d", &x);

function(x);

return 0;
}

void function(int x)
{
    float fx;

    fx=10/x;

    if(10 is divided by zero)// I dont know what to put here please help
        printf("division by zero is not allowed");
    else
        printf("f(x) is: %.5f",fx);

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void function(int);

int main()
{
     int x;

     printf("Enter x:");
     scanf("%d", &x);

function(x);

return 0;
}

void function(int x)
{
    float fx;

    if(x==0) // Simple!
        printf("division by zero is not allowed");
    else
        fx=10/x;            
        printf("f(x) is: %.5f",fx);

}
```

Answer (score 6):

This should do it. You need to check for division by zero before performing the division.

```
void function(int x)
{
    float fx;

    if(x == 0) {
        printf("division by zero is not allowed");
    } else {
        fx = 10/x;
        printf("f(x) is: %.5f",fx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

By default in UNIX, floating-point division by zero does not stop the program with an exception. Instead, it produces a result which is `infinity` or `NaN`. You can check that neither of these happened using `isfinite`.

```
x = y / z; // assuming y or z is floating-point
if ( ! isfinite( x ) ) cerr << "invalid result from division" << endl;
```

Alternately, you can check that the divisor isn't zero:

```
if ( z == 0 || ! isfinite( z ) ) cerr << "invalid divisor to division" << endl;
x = y / z;
```

Comment: It's not a floating point divide by zero though - it's integer (the result of the integer division expression is cast to a float afterwards).

Comment: @Paul: That is true in his code, but I didn't replicate his code. I added a comment, does that help?

Answer (score 1):

With C99 you can use [`fetestexcept(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fetestexcept) et alia.

Comment: That's only for floating point exceptions though ? The example above is for an integer divide by zero.