# Program will compile but not execute

Tags: c, gcc

I'm relatively new to C and I am trying to get a program to run. It's a program that lists all primes from 1 - 1000. The way I compile it is by typing `gcc Primes.c` into the command line and running it in NppExec.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int x;
int bool = 1;
int y;

main() {

    for (x = 2; x <= 100; x++) {
        bool = 1;
        for (y = 0; y <= floor(x/2); y++) {
            if (x % y == 0) {
               bool = 0;    
            }
        }

        if (bool == 1) {
            printf("%d\n", x);  
        }
    }
}
```

I type:

```
NPP_SAVE
CD $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
C:\MinGW32\bin\gcc.exe -g "$(FILE_NAME)" 
a
```

into the box and then execute. A window will pop up and say `a.exe` has stopped working. Any idea's on how to fix this?

Comment: Don't use `bool` as a variable name, it can actually be a defined type in C.

Comment: Don't attempt to evaluate `x % y` when `y` is `0`.  That's a divide-by-zero error.  You also don't need to use `floor(x/2)`.  Just `x/2` will suffice, since `x` is an integer.  Calling `floor` serves no purpose other than to convert it to `double` for no useful reason.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) so learn how to use it.

Comment: FYI, dependently types languages aim to solve this sort of problem. You can write your program in such a language so that it does not compile if you cannot prove that `y != 0`. See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/edwinb/0047a2aff46a0f49c881) for an example.

Comment: The key part in that gist is:
`safe_div : (x : Int) -> (y : Int) -> {auto p : so (y /= 0)} -> Int`
It takes two integers `x, y` and a proof that `y != 0`. If you give it non-integers, or if you can't show that `y != 0`, the program will not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug and many smaller issues in your code:

- You should not define `x`, `bool` and `y` as global variables, define these variables inside the body of the `main` function.
- The prototype for `main` is `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. `main()` is an obsolete form that is no longer supported by the C standard. `gcc` will accept it but `clang` will not by default.  You should also add `return 0;` at the end of `main`: although it was made implicit in C99, it is better style and more portable to older compilers.
- You should not use `bool` as a variable name, `bool` is usually used as a type name, name your flag `prime`.
- You should loop until `1000` as instructed.
- `y <= floor(x / 2)` does not work as expected: `x / 2` is an integer expression, it already has the value you expect, passing it to `floor` will convert it as a `double` and return the same value, `y` will be automatically converted to `double` for the comparison.  All this is unnecessary, `y <= x / 2` suffices. `floor` is the only function used from `<math.h>`, you can remove this include file too.
- Note that your condition will let the program perform way too many iterations, you should instead use `y * y <= x`.
- Initializing `y` to `0` will cause a division by zero when you compute `x % y`, invoking undefined behavior, the crash you observe.  You must initialize `y` to `2` because all numbers are divisible by `1`.
- You should exit the loop when you detect that `x` is composite, avoiding unnecessary iterations.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x, y, prime;

    for (x = 2; x <= 1000; x++) {
        prime = 1;
        for (y = 2; y * y <= x; y++) {
            if (x % y == 0) {
                prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (prime == 1) {
            printf("%d\n", x);  
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that about covers it. Only nit was the missed formatting `return 0` at the end of bulleted paragraph No. 2 (I'll let you fix it, I don't like edits to my answers over minutia)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: good point, I added extra precisions regarding the `return 0;`

Comment: `floor(x/2)` will not be converted back to `int`, silently or otherwise, as you claim.  What will happen is `y` will be converted to `double` and the comparison will be done as `double`.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
for (y = 0; y <= floor(x/2); y++) {
    if (x % y == 0) {
```

You initialize `y` to zero, then you directly divide by `y` (i.e. zero). Division by zero doesn't work, it will crash your program.

Answer (score 1):

The problem are these 2 lines:

```
for (y = 0; y <= floor(x/2); y++) {
    if (x % y == 0) {
```

What do you expect to get with `2 % 0`?

As per the standard:

> C99 6.5.5p5 - The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the second; the result of the % operator is the remainder. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined.

The crash is because of the Modulo operator when `y` is `0`.

[how to check if there is a division by zero in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485547/how-to-check-if-there-is-a-division-by-zero-in-c)